# How to set current date without timestamp in google sheets using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can we set the current date in Google Sheets without timestamp?

I am using the following script:

```
dateCell.setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)));
```

And this is what is set for the cell:

> 2/23/2021 6:00:00

However, when I press "Ctrl + :" to automatically insert current date in a cell, the following is inserted:

> 2/23/2021

What script can I use to only set the date without the timestamp?

Please note that I recorded a macro when pressing "Ctrl + :" and the following code was generated:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(date)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can specify your desired format with the [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) function:

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

This should work given `spreadsheet` is defined already in your current code:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "MM/dd/yyyy");
spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(date)
```

**Minimal Reproducible Example:**

Add the date to cell A1:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const timezone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of your sheet
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, "MM/dd/yyyy");
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you running loop, format this way :

```
var date = utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[3]),"GMT","dd/MMM/yyyy") 
//row[3] is colounm number in data array where is your dates are
```

otherwise without loop :

```
var date = utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT","dd/MMM/yyyy")
```